# "Qu'en est-il de...", qu'est-ce ça veut dire?

Tags: sens

Salut tout le monde,

En expliquant le mot "chauve-souris", un site internet pose la question suivant: "Qu'en est-il des ailes, par example?". Qu'est-ce que la question, et généralement l'expression "en être" veut dire?

Suivant vous pouvez trouvez l'explication dans laquelle j'ai trouvé l'expression:

> Même si l’association de chauve et souris est envisageable pour décrire l’animal, l’absence de poils n’est pas vraiment la première différence qui saute aux yeux. Qu’en est-il des ailes, par exemple ? Est-ce qu’on ne devrait pas plutôt parler de souris volante ?

Merci bien à toutes et tous!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In this context, the question is not necessarily "what is 'en être', " (which has many uses) but rather what is the expression **"Qu'en est-il de..."**

Here,

> "**Qu'en est-il de**s ailes, par exemple ?"

could be translated as

> "**What about** the wings, for example?"

in English.

For this paragraph, the author is questioning the description of bats in French (literally "bald mice") in saying that the lack of hair on bats (hence "*chauve*") is not really the first distinguishable attribute.

The author is suggesting an alternative trait that is seen more immediately recognizable in bats - the wings.